# When counting source files and LOC with locate and find - why do Python files come up different?

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, find, locate

I am having trouble understanding why `find` and `locate` would work differently for C and Python source files. My goal is to count the number source files and the sum of their source code lines for a given language. I used both `find` and `locate` to compare outputs (`updatedb` was just run prior to this with `sudo` to make sure `locate` reports current results).

For C files this works as expected, the number of source files is the same

```
$ find / -name *.c |& grep -v "Permission denied" | wc -l
1056
$ locate *.c | wc -l
1056
```

Using `xargs`, the sum of source code lines also come up the same.

```
$ locate *.c | xargs wc -l | tail -3
     138 /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.el7.ppc64/scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders.c
     147 /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.el7.ppc64/scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c
  705376 total

$ find / -name *.c |& grep -v "Permission denied" | xargs wc -l | tail -3
    2994 /opt/Python-3.6.2/Objects/listobject.c
     821 /opt/Python-3.6.2/Objects/bytes_methods.c
  705376 total
```

Just to test, this also works for files with a `.java` extension - I get the same consistent results. However, when I repeat the same with for Python files (ie. `.py` extension)

Source file number matches.

```
$ find / -name *.py |& grep -v "Permission denied" | wc -l
9249
$ locate *.py | wc -l
9249
```

But the sum of lines of code for Python files gives very different results.

```
$ locate *.py | xargs wc -l | tail -3
wc: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/script: No such file or directory
wc: template: No such file or directory
wc: (dev).py: No such file or directory
wc: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/script: No such file or directory
wc: template.py: No such file or directory
     220 /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.el7.ppc64/scripts/rt-tester/rt-tester.py
     129 /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.el7.ppc64/scripts/tracing/draw_functrace.py
  753350 total

$ find / -name *.py |& grep -v "Permission denied" | xargs wc -l | tail -3
wc: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/script: No such file or directory
wc: template: No such file or directory
wc: (dev).py: No such file or directory
wc: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/script: No such file or directory
wc: template.py: No such file or directory
    1919 /opt/Python-3.6.2/python-gdb.py
      69 /opt/Python-3.6.2/python-config.py
 1034101 total
```

Can someone explain why this is the case? What's so different about Python files (I can't really believe it has to do with the file type, but I'm stumped). What am I missing here?

Same odd results under Ubuntu and RH

I run `updatedb` with `sudo`, but I'm running all of these command as a regular user.

Comment: Your result for both commands should be inconsistent because once number of maximum arguments for a command is reached ( it's called MAXARGS ) , the xargs will start padding new wc command. So it outputs "total" several times during the process, and it gets lost because of tail. Try removing tail and see if multiple lines "total" come up.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy When I read your comment it made intuitive sense to me (too), but I just re-ran both commands without the final pipe that uses tail and I end up with the same results :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems with your commands.

First, `locate *.c` only looks for files matching `*.c` if you run it in a directory that doesn't contain any file whose name matches `*.c`. Otherwise the shell expands `*.c` to the list of matching files. That's probably not happening, otherwise you'd get a lot fewer matches, but leaving unquoted globs like this is a bad habit because it *will* bite you one day. (It's a frequent topic on this site.) The same goes for `find -name *.c`. Instead, write

```
locate '*.c' …
find / -name '*.c' …
```

or something similar.

There are some common why `locate` and `find` might give different results. They don't seem to apply in your case since you're getting the same number of hits, but once again this is something you need to be aware of.

- `locate` results are cached from the last run of `updatedb`. This usually runs once at night. `find` results calculated each time you run the command.
- Depending on the system, on which `locate` implementation you have and on how it's configured, it may let you see only publicly accessible files (e.g. GNU findutils, rather than mlocate or slocate), or it may make an approximation of the files that you're allowed to access (e.g. because there's a complex setup involving Linux security modules that distinguish between applications trying to access the file).
- The pattern `*SUFFIX` mean the same thing to `locate` and to `find -name` (assuming that `SUFFIX` doesn't contain slashes or wildcards), but other patterns don't. For example `locate foo` is equivalent to `find / -name '*foo*'`, not to `find / -name 'foo'`.

Another thing that might, but probably doesn't, cause problems is that you've piped error messages from `find` into the data processing part of your command. You strip out lines containing `Permission denied`, which causes you to miss files containing this as part of their name (ok, you probably don't have any), and causes any error message that doesn't contain `Permission denied` to be interpreted as an input line. It is rarely a good idea to mix data output with error output, and it's absurd here. If you want to ignore errors, redirect them to `/dev/null`:

```
find … 2>/dev/null | …
```

What is definitely biting you is that `xargs` expects an input syntax that's different from what `find` produces. In the input of `xargs`, any whitespace separates items, not just line breaks. The three characters `\'"` are also parsed specially. Spaces are common in file names and all other characters are permitted apart from `/` and from null bytes. One of the lines that `xargs` receives as input is

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/script template (dev).py
```

For `xargs`, that's three items: `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/script`, `template` and `(dev).py`. The reason for the error messages from `wc` should now be clear.

There are several solutions for this. One is to use the null-delimited format for `find` and `xargs`. This works with any file name, even file names containing newlines (which are permitted, but uncommon).

```
find / -name '*.py' -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l | tail -3
```

Another is to forget about the problematic `xargs` and make `find` invoke the command directly.

```
find / -name '*.py' -exec wc -l {} + | tail -3
```

The first solution may be applicable to your `locate` implementation, check if it has a `-0` option. The second solution is specific to `find`. If you're stuck with newline-delimited output from `locate`, and you have the GNU version of `xargs`, then you can use `-d '\n'` to make it parse the input as newline-delimited without any form of quoting.

```
locate '*.py' | xargs -d '\n' wc -l | tail -3
```

This was your main problem. An additional problem is that there's a maximum length to the command line. The `xargs` command (or the `-exec … {} +` action of `find`) puts as many file names as it can on a command line, and if they don't all fit, then the command (here, `wc -l`) is executed multiple times, once for each batch of files. With `tail -3`, you're only seeing the last two files and the total for the last batch (assuming that there are at least two files in the last batch). The files in the previous batches are not reflected in this output. Since `find` and `locate` may not report files in the same order, you may see different results.

How to solve the maximum length problem depends on what you want to do with the data. If all you want is grand totals, then one way (assuming no newlines in file names) is to count all `total` lines.

```
… | xargs -d '\n' wc -l | awk '/^[0-9]+\ttotal$/ {total += $1} END {print total}'
```

Comment: `locate` doesn't include hidden files like find, does it ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy `locate` and `find` both include hidden files. It's basically only shell wildcards (i.e. `*` in the shell, not `*` in `find`) and `ls` that ignore dot files.

Comment: Thank you for all this info and advice re pushing error messages to /dev/null rather than handling it like I did. It'll take me a while to digest this wealth of information - I did realize after I posted that using quotes around my "*.c" would be advisable. And the alternatives offered to find the numbers I was looking for. My quick initial question is, why did I not run into problems with the .java and .c files? I apologize if the answer is your extensive reply, in which case just ignore my question, I will read read your answer carefully.

Comment: PS: Feels pretty humbling.

Comment: @Levon You didn't run into problems with `.java` and `.c` files because none of them had a name containing a space, or was contained in a directory whose name contains a space. It's rare for source code files to contain spaces in their name, usually people stick to valid identifiers in the language. I wonder how this Python file (which is part of a distribution package) got its name.

Comment: I was re-reading your message more carefully this afternoon, did you mean `The patterns *SUFFIX and *SUFFIX mean`" to be `The patterns *SUFFIX and *SUFFIX* mean `?

Comment: @Levon I don't remember what I meant to write. `*foo*` does not mean the same thing because `find` matches only the file's base name whereas `locate` matches the directory part as well, so `locate *foo*` would also find `/path/to/foo/bar`.